# get User name in wordpress and post with form

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

using this code in wordpress: `<input hidden="hidden" type="text" value="<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>" name="USER" />`

I am trying to post the current logged in user (wordpress) to another php file. It works fine for all my other inputs but somehow USER returns blank. Any ideas on why this might happen?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Wow. Stop right here! You aren't doing what I think you are I hope? Do not trust that username!!! Why do you need to pass the username that way. Simply just use `wp_get_current_user();` in the page which handles the form.

Comment: Because input fields can be changed by the user.

Comment: yes but that function is not supported outside of the wp environement, so i get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to work :)

```
<?php
$user = get_current_user();

   echo $current_user->user_login;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used invalid properties of the `input` element: there is no property named `hidden`. Also, you want the property `type` to equal `hidden`. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php wp_get_current_user(); ?>" name="USER" />
```

See also [the list of valid properties of the input element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML code to ensure that `wp_get_current_user()` returned something meaningful and the `value` attribute is set?

Comment: it doesn't. that's the problem :)